# Why does the default razor view template use an h2 tag for the title instead of h1?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

When I create a new razor view in ASP.NET MVC4, the title is automatically enclosed in `h2` tags:

```
@{
   ViewBag.Title = "ViewPage1";
}

<h2>ViewPage1</h2>
```

I follow the rule that a page should have one `h1` tag and the hierarchy of heading tags should be respected. I assume that the ASP.NET MVC team put some thought into this, so I'm wondering why they chose to markup the title with `h2` instead of `h1`.

Comment: Since the only people who can likely answer this are people who worked on it, I'd suggest tweeting one of them the link to this question.

Comment: I don't know who they are and I don't use twitter. Perhaps I could have phrased my question to ask if there's a valid reason for this rather than "what we're they thinking". ASP.NET MVC and razor especially seem very well thought out but every time I create a view I wonder about the h2 tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They didn't put that much thought. That's the first thing I change/delete when I create a new view.

Answer (score 2):

Probably assuming that you will have a `<h1>` in your **layout**.

Of course, they don't put a `h1` in but it might be a legacy hangover of sorts

Comment: That's a good explanation but it assumes that every page using the layout has the same title or the title is set in a section.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that they think you could already have a  in your page.
You can change the scaffolding templates that generate those views in order to forget that issue.

I have all my scaffolding view templates modified in order to need to change them as little as possible.